# How to encode a numpy array with PIL, like opencv's cv2.imencode()?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, flask, python-imaging-library

I'm making a REST API with flask, and I want to send an image to my server. So far I did-

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import cv2

image= Image.open("image.jpg")
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
image= np.array(image)

_, JPEG = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)

response_raw = requests.post(test_url, data=JPEG.tostring(), headers=headers)
```

Now this works perfectly fine, but I unfortunatly use OPENCV for my final project. So I testest around with PIL, trying to replicate the `cv2.imencode()` method, but It didnt work. I did this, replacing the `cv2.imencode` method (and removing `image=np.array(image)`-

```
buffer = BytesIO()
image.save(buffer, format="JPEG")

JPEG = buffer.getvalue()
```

This didn't work as `type(JPEG)` returns `<class 'bytes'>`, whereas the working code (with `cv2.imencode("jpg", img)`) retured `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

How do I do the encoding process on a numpy array?

Comment: Try, `JPEG = np.array(buffer.getvalue())`, what do you get?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're confused. a `bytes` object contains bytes. a numpy array of type uint8 (which you have there...) also contains bytes.

Comment: Ok, I was just very confused with the whole thing.  np.array(buffer.get_value()) seems to work. Thanks! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

`JPEG = np.array(buffer.getvalue())` seems to work

Answer (score 0):

```
    with io.BytesIO() as output:
        Image.fromarray(img).save(output, format="jpeg")
        return np.frombuffer(output.getvalue(), dtype=np.dtype('b'))
```